# Good book on mechanisms

Tags: design, mechanism

I am working with students (9th & 10th grade) on robotics and wanted to get a good book which covers basic mechanisms.  Does anyone have any recommendations.  Searching Google or Amazon yields many results, however, I thought the community might have a standard book to use.

Comment: This question has the makings of a list question which are generally frowned upon in the Stack Exchange community. It would also help if you were more specific about the age group the children belong too. The [FAQ](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#close) may be able to help you formulate this question so as to elicit higher quality responses.

Comment: In addition to what DaemonMaker said, you may want to ask the question in [chat] -- that's the place for such discussion-y/list-y things :)

Comment: This is quite a broad topic, can you narrow it down a little bit?  For example, are you thinking about mobile robots, various types of robot arms, flying robots, etc?  You've looked on Google and Amazon already, so presumably you had something in mind (but nothing jumped out at you as meeting that criteria).  What would make you say "oh yes, _this_ is the book I need"?

Comment: Henry T. Brown. "507 Mechanical Movements". 1908. [Wikipedia: Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanism_(engineering))

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Commodore63 (showing our age there \*8'). A better question title might have been something like *"Is there a standard robotics textbook for teaching X year old students?"*, but that may have just moved us from *not constructive* close votes to *too localised* close votes. Also, as a Brit, I'm not sure what ages 9-10th grade covers, though I assume 15-16 year olds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best book I have seen on the subject of mechanisms is [Mechanisms And Mechanical Devices by Neil Sclater and Nicholas P. Chironis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mechanisms-Mechanical-Sourcebook-Nicholas-Chironis/dp/0071361693/).

[image: Mechanisms And Mechanical Devices]

It's got loads of great mechanisms in it, from simple linear movements:

[image]

... to complex packaging machines:

[image]

It also covers robotics.